# Extracting address, city, latitude and longitude from OSM XML using Python

Tags: python-2.7, openstreetmap

I have OSM XML of size 1tb. I want to build a data store that contains street, city, state, country, zip code, latitude, longitude.

To do so, I need help in parsing OSM XML using python to collect the list of address and lat lon cordinates.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You will need a [geocoder](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines), a simple script will not be enough since [addresses](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Addresses) are stored hierarchically in OSM (using a combination of address nodes/ways and boundary relations). This means you have to perform various calculations while building your address database. Better use an existing geocoder such as [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I want to build an autocomplete address lookup for our web app.  It should be similar to Google AutoComplete.  Is there any way we achieve this ?. If we have data like the above format, we can implement easily. Could you please suggest any other approaches?

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this.